# JMX threads are not closing

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

when I am doing `JMX connection` through a thread by following code,

```
private  JMXConnector initConnection() throws Exception{
    JMXServiceURL serviceURL = null;

    try {
        String URL = MessageFormat.format(connectorURL, new Object[]{hostName, port});
        serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(URL);

        final Map<String, String[]> environment = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
        environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, new String[]{userName, password});

        return JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, environment);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

following threads are not destroying, even though i closed the connection and destroyed the thread that creates jmx connection

GC Daemon,RMI RenewClean, RMI Scheduler(0) these threads are not destroying in java JMX connection.

code in connection close

```
public void closeConnection() {
    if(jmxc != null){
        try{
            jmxc.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            jmxc = null;
        }
    }
}



public void createMBeanServerConnection() throws Exception
{
    try
    {  
        jmxc  = initConnection();

        mbServerConnection = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }  
 }
```

This is the full context

```
public class Test1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

        Thread.sleep(120000);
        Test t = new Test();
        t.main(args);
        Thread.sleep(120000);
    }

}







public class Test
{

    private String hostName = "";
    private String port = "";
    private String userName = "";
    private String password = "";
    private String connectorURL = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://{0}:{1}/jmxrmi";
    private JMXConnector jmxc = null;
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.hostName = args[0];
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        t.port = args[1];
        t.jmxc = t.initConnection(); 
        MBeanServerConnection mbsc = t.jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
        mbsc.queryMBeans(new ObjectName("*.*:*"), null);
        t.closeConnection();
    }

    private  JMXConnector initConnection() 
    {

        JMXServiceURL serviceURL = null;

        try 
        {

            String URL = MessageFormat.format(connectorURL, new Object[]{hostName, port});
            System.out.println(URL);
            serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(URL);
            final Map<String, String[]> environment = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
            environment.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, new String[]{userName, password});
            System.out.println(serviceURL);

            return JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, environment);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }


    public void closeConnection() 
    {

        if(jmxc != null)
        {
            try
            {
                jmxc.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                jmxc = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should work, had the same issue myself two weeks ago.  Is closeConnection called in a finally block to to that it is called?

Comment: also try printing out any IOException

Comment: If connection is closed from server side (remote location) , than i am getting jmxc as null.

Comment: please any body help me..

Comment: are you sure that `closeConnection` is being called - do you log it? are you sure that `jmxc` is not being set to null somewhere?

Comment: jmxc set to null in all conditions and closeConnection is calling when ever server is running... , i also tried to set jmxc = null after jmx.close operation , even after that also daemon threads are not closing...

Comment: please show a code snippet of how you are calling this code

Comment: added the code of callng method

Comment: I can not see where `closeConnection` is being called from

Comment: i am calling it making connection i am calling closeConnection

Comment: can't help you if you will not show your code

Answer (score 3):

You should **do your task**, then **close the connection**.

```
public void createMBeanServerConnection() throws Exception
{
    try
    {  
        jmxc  = initConnection();

        mbServerConnection = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();

        doYourThing();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;

    }  finally {

        closeConnection();

    }

 }
```